# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isnumeric'

Tags: python, pandas

Slightly confused as I'm positive I've had this working before.

I've created the following method...

```
def p2f(x):
    if x.strip('%').isnumeric():
        return float(x.strip('%'))/100
    elif x in ['SUPP', 'NEW', 'LOWCOV', 'NA', '']:
        return 0.0
    else:
        return x
```

but when I run it on my imported CSV file, it produces this error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isnumeric'
```

Although I can see that `isnumeric` is an attribute of `str` in the documention:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.isnumeric.html?highlight=isnumeric#pandas.Series.str.isnumeric

Unless I'm not interpreting the information correctly?

Comment: The `str.isnumeric()` method is Python 3.x only. Are you using Python 2.x?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str.isnumeric()` is only available on Python 3. The error indicates you are using Python 2 instead, where only [`unicode.isnumeric()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#unicode.isnumeric) exists.

You should really use [`str.isdecimal()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.isdecimal.html), or better yet, use *exception handling*:

```
def p2f(x):
    try:
        return float(x.strip('%'))/100
    except ValueError:
        return 0.0 if x in ('SUPP', 'NEW', 'LOWCOV', 'NA', '') else x
```

`.isnumeric()` matches 430 Unicode codepoints in the BMP that `float()` won't accept, and there are codepoints that `.isdigit()` returns true for that are also not convertible.

You can generate your own table to check with:

```
for i in range(2 ** 16):
    c = chr(i)
    if c.isnumeric() or c.isdigit() or c.isdecimal():
        try:
            f = float(c)
        except ValueError:
            f = '<not convertible>'
        di, de, nu = ('\u2705' if test() else '\u274c' for test in (c.isdigit, c.isdecimal, c.isnumeric))
        print(f'{c!a:<6} {c}\tdigit: {di}   decimal: {de}   numeric: {nu}  float: {f}')
```

which produces output like:

```
'0'    0    digit: ✅   decimal: ✅   numeric: ✅  float: 0.0
'1'    1    digit: ✅   decimal: ✅   numeric: ✅  float: 1.0
'2'    2    digit: ✅   decimal: ✅   numeric: ✅  float: 2.0
'3'    3    digit: ✅   decimal: ✅   numeric: ✅  float: 3.0
'4'    4    digit: ✅   decimal: ✅   numeric: ✅  float: 4.0
'5'    5    digit: ✅   decimal: ✅   numeric: ✅  float: 5.0
'6'    6    digit: ✅   decimal: ✅   numeric: ✅  float: 6.0
'7'    7    digit: ✅   decimal: ✅   numeric: ✅  float: 7.0
'8'    8    digit: ✅   decimal: ✅   numeric: ✅  float: 8.0
'9'    9    digit: ✅   decimal: ✅   numeric: ✅  float: 9.0
'\xb2' ²    digit: ✅   decimal: ❌   numeric: ✅  float: <not convertible>
'\xb3' ³    digit: ✅   decimal: ❌   numeric: ✅  float: <not convertible>
'\xb9' ¹    digit: ✅   decimal: ❌   numeric: ✅  float: <not convertible>
'\xbc' ¼    digit: ❌   decimal: ❌   numeric: ✅  float: <not convertible>
'\xbd' ½    digit: ❌   decimal: ❌   numeric: ✅  float: <not convertible>
'\xbe' ¾    digit: ❌   decimal: ❌   numeric: ✅  float: <not convertible>
```

and you'll find that only the `decimal` column has crosses for all non-convertible  codepoints.

If you want to use `isdecimal()` in Python 2, you'd have to decode your bytestring to Unicode first.