# Python: how do I use isnumeric()

Tags: python

Can someone kindly explain why the following throws an exception? And what should I do with variable `s` to find out whether it contains a number?

```
s = str(10)
if s.isnumeric():
    print s
```

When I read Python documentation it seems to me the above should work. See:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=isnumeric#str.isnumeric

But what I get is:

> "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isnumeric'"

Any help is most appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: What Python version are you using?

Comment: you are trying in python version 2 so this error

Comment: Don't read the python 3 docs if you're using python 2.

Comment: You could use [`isdigit()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=isdigit#str.isdigit), if that helps. It's not exactly the same, but it's available in Python 2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isnumeric'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49263568/attributeerror-str-object-has-no-attribute-isnumeric). It would be beneficial if you gave more information about your problem, like the python version you're using.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I was using Python inside Google's appengine, and that turns out to be version 2.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

replace `isnumeric()` with `isdigit()` as

```py
s = str(10)
if s.isdigit():
    print s
```

Comment: @meowgoesthedog solution was specific to above example, where number is integer

Answer (score 2):

for python 2 **isdigit()** and for python 3 **isnumeric()**

> python 2

```
s = str(10)
if s.isdigit():
    print s
```

> python 3

```
 s = str(10)
 if s.isnumeric():
    print(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are obviously using python 2, so a such method does not exist.

That said, the most pythonic way would be to try to convert it

```
try:
    print(float(s))  # or int(s)
except ValueError:
    print("s must be numeric")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `replace` with `isdigit`:

```
print(s.replace('.', '').isdigit())
```

Comment: Wow... that was clean !

Comment: @programmer Lol, happy it's good